# How to catch an incrementing iterator exception?

Tags: c++

I have an empty `vector<int>` and I try to increment its **iterator**, but the iterator is empty, so it should throw an exception. That is why I try to catch it with a universal `catch` clause. Sadly it doesn't work. I get only a message `vector iterator not incrementable`. Which exception should I catch?

```
vector<int> myVec;

auto iterator = myVec.begin();

try {
    ++iterator;
} catch(exception& e) { //universal exception doesn't catch an exception
    Logger::WriteMessage("Caught an Exception");
}
```

Comment: There is no exception - it's undefined behaviour.  The solution is to not iterate beyond the iterator's bounds.

Comment: "*so it should throw an exception*" - says who?  Does incrementing a raw pointer throw an exception?  No.  Neither does incrementing an iterator past its container's bounds. Now, if you try to *dereference* an invalid iterator (just like dereferencing an invalid pointer), then all kinds of nasty things can happen. Still no guarantee that an exception will be thrown, though.

Comment: I come from Java, so I thought that a program ends if it reaches its end or if it throws unhandled exception. I didn't think it could somehow end just because without throwing anything.

Comment: It is not ending "just because".  It is ending because it is reaching the end of its code.  Simply incrementing an iterator will not throw an exception, the code will just keep running normally to the next statement, if there is one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Though to be clear, it's "chance" that it does so.

Comment: AFAIK, "vector iterator not incrementable" is not a runtime exception error message, it is an assertion error message, so you are not likely to see it unless you are running a debug build of the STL inside of a debugger, and a failed assertion can kill the program immediately.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I use a debugger, but in this case I didn't assert anything. The program just stops at the line `++iterator`, opens a file with a line `_DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterator not incrementable");` and it doesn't let me step-out.

Comment: It is a debug assertion inside a debug version of the `vector` source code. The STL is allowing you to debug the problem, and then the program will end immediately if the debugger does not handle the error.  There is nothing to catch in your code, which is why your `catch` does not work. You won't even see the error if you compile in release mode, your code will just have a logic bomb in it if you try to use the invalid iterator. This is a debugging tool, not a runtime error handling tool.